# Passing user credentials in the zeppelin REST Api while running a notebook

Tags: angularjs, rest, apache-zeppelin

I have a Angular app where it accepts the user credentials in the SSO login. Based on the user looged in I have to pull a chart from zeppelin notebook, for the entities the user is subscribed to. 
I want to pass these credentials to my zeppelin note book while running a notebook thru the REST api.

Can somebody help me in identifying how do I Pass the user credentials from my angular to the zeppelin rest API notebook execution call?

Comment: Are you using [NGINX](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/security/authentication.html) or [shirio](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/security/shiroauthentication.html) authentication?